# ASP Gridview Select statement not working (GUID)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I'm using ASP.net to use a gridview. The gridview's sql data source is a select statement where ID  = a value (a GUID) from a querystring.

However, when I try and preview it, it doesn't show any results. If I change it to a different type (int) of 1, then it works fine and shows results.

If I do the select statement in SQL Server Management Studio (with the GUID), it works fine and shows the results.

Here's the code for the data:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLDataSourceL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [FName], [Date] FROM [Table1] WHERE (([FName] = @FName) AND ([Type] = @Type)) ORDER BY [Date] DESC, [FName]">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="FName" QueryStringField="id" Type="Object" />
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="X" Name="Type" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

(I've changed the column names).

Hope you can help.

Comment: What is primary key in your `Table1`?

Comment: Right, and your `FNAME` column storing GUID in database?

Comment: are you getting result in gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the QueryStringParameter to the suitable type, eg:

```
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="FName" QueryStringField="id" Type="String" />
```

Comment: That worked a treat. It seems such an obvious thing to look over! Thank you